# Error while Accessing Private Func. from Public Func. inside a Class

Tags: php

I have the following class structure. When run the post() function, I receive an error `Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function curl_post()`.

```
class POST {

    private function encode($data) {
    }

    private function curl_post($data) {
        encode($data);
    }

    public function post($data) {
        $post = curl_post($data);
        print_r($post);
    }
}
```

What is causing this error? Do I have to use something like `$this->` to access the private function?

Comment: `$post = curl_post($data);` ==> `$post = $this->curl_post($data);`

Comment: `encode($data);`  ==> `$this->encode($data);`

Comment: I didn't DV, but yes - You should definitely must use `$this` when you need to reference to the current class instance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To call sibling object methods, prefix the call with `$this->`:

```
class POST {

    private function encode($data) {
    }

    private function curl_post($data) {
        $this->encode($data);
    }

    public function post($data) {
        $post = $this->curl_post($data);
        print_r($post);
    }
}
```

From the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php):

> The pseudo-variable $this is available when a method is called from within an object context. $this is a reference to the calling object (usually the object to which the method belongs...